# Rate limiting parse.com background jobs

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I have some data in parse.com that needs to be updated by a background job. There are around 100 hundred rows. Updating each row uses 3 queries of the parse api. I am only allowed 30 queries a second, so only the first 9 rows get updated each time I run the job, and any users who happen to access the system during that second will get errors.

Is there a simple way to put pauses in the job so that it only updates a row after 200ms or so, and the job then only uses half the queries available? It means the job will take about 20 seconds to run, rather than just one second, but that's a totally acceptable tradeoff.

The code is structured roughly like:

```
Parse.Cloud.job("UpdateData", function (request, status) {
  Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

  (new Parse.Query("Table"))
    .find()
    .then(function (rows) {
      rows.forEach(function (row) {
        // Some queries happen here
        ...
        row
          .set(...)
          .save();
      });
      status.success();
    }, function (error) {
      status.error();
    });
});
```

I don't think I can use `setTimeout` or `setInterval` easily on this code (I'm not even sure if they are allowed on parse.com cloud code). JS doesn't support anything like `sleep()` or `wait()`.

Comment: Are you sure background jobs work like that? I thought you got one job per 20req/sec with other limits on the job, but not req/sec limits. Otherwise, the above scenario would be incredibly common.

Comment: I'm not sure, if thats why, but my job is finding 168 rows, then only updating the first 9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `Parse.Object.saveAll` to save all object at once and also to chain Parse promises in a series as @mbm29414 mention if you need other queries in your forEach loop.

The following code snippet shows a simple example of saving object at once with `Parse.Object.saveAll`:

```
Parse.Cloud.job("UpdateData", function (request, status) {
  Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

  (new Parse.Query("Table"))
    .find()
    .then(function (rows) {
      var toSaveList = [];
      var promise = new Parse.Promise();
      rows.forEach(function (row) {
        // Some queries happen here
        ...
        row.set(...);
        ...
        toSaveList.push(row)
      });
      Parse.Object.saveAll(toSaveList, function() {
        promise.resolve();
      }, function() {
        promise.reject();
      });
      return promise;
    })
    .then(function() {
      status.success();
    }, function() {
      status.error();
    });
});
```

Comment: Using `saveAll` is a much better idea - that is what I have now implemented.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that you're returning `status.success()` in a synchronous fashion, rather than waiting for the code looping to complete.

Try this (modified from [chaining Parse promises in a series](https://www.parse.com/docs/js_guide#promises-series)):

```
Parse.Cloud.job("UpdateData", function (request, status) {
  Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
  var query = new Parse.Query("Table");
  query.find().then(function (rows) {
      var promise = Parse.Promise.as();
      _.each(rows, function(row) {
          promise = promise.then(function () {
              row.set(...);
              return row.save();              
          });
      });
  }).then(function () {
      // All got saved
      status.success();

  }, function (error) {
      // Something went wrong somewhere
      status.error(error);

  });
});
```